# Can I filter all questions "except tag-X"?

Tags: support, search, tag-search

## How can I most easily use a specifc tag as *exclusion* criteria ?

Say a site has the tags: [foo-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-1) [foo-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-2) [foo-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-3) ... [foo-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-n)

I can easily find all questions of [foo-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-x) by just clicking that tag or going to: `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-x`

I can also use the [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to find questions which contain either of the tags [foo-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-x) [foo-y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-y) using the search string:

`[foo-x] or [foo-y]`

And I can do the same to find questions containing both the tags [foo-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-x) [foo-y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-y) using the search string:

`[foo-x] and [foo-y]`

Now what I would like to find are all questions containing *any* tag but *not* the tag [foo-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-x).

**Can I do this?**

Essentially, I want to filter *out* topics I'm not interested in, rather than search *for* a specific topic.

---

Thanks to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320622/how-do-i-filter-java-but-exclude-android-in-rss-or-searches) question I now know that

I can search for "contains [foo-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-x) but does not contain [foo-y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo-y)" using a simple minus-sign in front of the tag, i.e. by the search string:

`[foo-x] -[foo-y]`

However, just using the `-[foo-y]` does not give me what I want. It seems I can only search for *"Find X, except if Y"* but not for *"Find ALL, except if Y"*.

Comment: Does http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320622/how-do-i-filter-java-but-exclude-android-in-rss-or-searches contain the info. you need?

Comment: @JonClements Yes it does, thanks. It was the MINUS sign I didn't know off. I tried "not" and "!" but didn't think of that. thanks. Should I self-answer my question to have it closed, or do you prefer to close/filter it?

Comment: @JonClements Ah, it does only *nearly* what I want. I will amend my question in an edit...

Comment: Yes - I wasn't sure - there's also a difference between the old nav and new nav stuff... so might want to add in which one you're using as well.

Comment: `[*] -[foo-y]` should do what you want...

Comment: @JonClements *Nearly*. It did not work, but `is:question -[foo-y]` did.

Comment: @BmyGuest related if the tag exclusion failed without `is:q`: [Hard to exclude tags in search for new nav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259915/hard-to-exclude-tags-in-search-for-new-nav)

Comment: @JonClements How do I know / choose if I use the 'old' or the 'new' nav? (Until now, I was not aware there is such a differentiation.)

Comment: @BmyGuest go to your profile and preferences/settings page - eg: http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me

Comment: @JonClements *old* nav then, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to help from the comments, the answer to my question is:

**To search for all questions which do *not* contain a specific tag [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) use the following search string:**

> `is:question -[foo]`

Example: If you are interested in puzzles but *not* riddles, you may use the following search on PuzzlingSE:

> [is:question -[riddle]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20-%5Briddle%5D)

---

This is using the *old* navigation box, i.e. I have *not* enabled the beta-testing on the preference page.