# Is there a way to exclude tags in the question filter?

Tags: support, filtering

In the question filter box on e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions, is there a way to exclude tags?

The usual search box technique of prefacing the tag name with a `-`, described in [How to search for questions not containing a certain tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271236/how-to-search-for-questions-not-containing-a-certain-tag), does not appear to work in the filter box.

I'd like to make a new tab that is [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) but excludes [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

---

This is the version of the filter page I am using:

[image]

Comment: You using new new new (?) nav?

Comment: Use `not` instead of `-`. [`[java] not [android]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20not%20android).

Comment: @Braiam Is there a nav newer than the old new nav?

Comment: @MikeM. There were at least 2 "new" navs.

Comment: @Braiam Really? Hunh, guess I never noticed. I assume I'm using the newest. What changed between them?

Comment: @Braiam Dunno, I've lost track. There's a screenshot.

Comment: @MikeM. Awesome, that worked, thanks. How's that answer box allergy? I think they make a cream for it, ya know. :D

Comment: Oh, I also just realized that whatever you type in the search box (traditional one on top right) on that page gets copied to the filter box. So another way is to do `[java] -[android]` in the search box, then it fills the filter with `[java] not [android]`. Didn't notice that before.

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate. :-P   Surely this has been answered before.

Comment: @MikeM. Fwiw I put in a pretty good effort, but I welcome better search-fu. I couldn't even find one on MSE.

Comment: How about this one? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320622/how-do-i-filter-java-but-exclude-android-in-rss-or-searches

Comment: @MikeM. Hmm... Well, the answer is there. The dupe it's linked to loses the info again, unfortunately. The question is generic enough that it could apply. I respect my fellow +java -android brethren. And I can't ignore how much time you apparently spent looking for that, lol. All right, I'll take it!